# MYSQL does not return data after using UNION with count

Tags: mysql, database

I'm trying to get the total count of branches + count for branches per city + count for branches per category, then trying to get the name of the city and the name of the category, problem is COUNT(*) is working just fine, but the SELECT * after are not showing in the response, it only shows the return from COUNT(*), what could be the problem and how can I solve it ?

this is my code

```
    let query = `SELECT 
            (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tbl_branches ) as totalBranches,
            (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tbl_branch_info WHERE city_id=${city_id === undefined ? '1' : `${city_id}`}) as totalCities,
            (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tbl_branch_info WHERE category_id=${category_id === undefined ? '1' : `${category_id}`}) as totalCat
            UNION
            SELECT * FROM tbl_cities as cities WHERE id='${city_id}'
            UNION
            SELECT * FROM tbl_provider_types as catID WHERE id='${category_id}'      
            `;
```

Comment: This is presenting as an xy problem. Instead, see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 0):

The problem you are having is because when you use UNION, you need to make sure that each statement being UNION'ed returns the same number and types of columns as the first statement.  This is described in the help [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/union.html#union-result-set).

I don't know the rest of your data, but I would guess that you ultimately want to JOIN these tables together to collect the counts with names of the cities and categories.  Give JOINing these tables together with a GROUP BY clause a shot and if it doesn't work out, submit a new question!

Comment: i have tried selecting one column too in each SELECT COUNT(*) and SELECT * it sent back an error , like SELECT(id) from tbl_branches, didnt workout for me

Comment: also i have thought of JOINING but problem is cities and categories have no mutual or common foreign key